# Prob. 9, Exercises 8.14, in Apostol's CALCULUS Vol II: If the derivatives of a scalar field on an open ball vanish in $n$ independent directions,

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

Here is Prob. 9, Exercises 8.14, in the book *Calculus* Vol II by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

> Assume $f$ is differentiable at each point of an $n$-ball $B(\mathbf{a})$. If $f^\prime( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0$ for $n$ independent vectors $\mathbf{y}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{y}_n$ and for every $\mathbf{x}$ in $B(\mathbf{a})$, prove that $f$ is constant on $B(\mathbf{a})$.

My Attempt:

> First we note that the $n$ independent vectors $\mathbf{y}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{y}_n$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written (in a unique way) as a linear combination of these vectors.
>
> Since $f$ is differentiable at each point of $B(\mathbf{a})$, therefore $f$ is continuous on $B( \mathbf{a})$.
>
> Since $f$ is differentiable at each point $\mathbf{x} \in B(\mathbf{a})$, all the partial derivatives $D_1 f( \mathbf{x}), \ldots, D_n f(\mathbf{x})$ of $f$ exist, and for every $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have 
>   $$ f^\prime( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = \nabla f(\mathbf{x} ) \cdot \mathbf{y}.  \tag{1}$$
>
> Let $\mathbf{x}$ be an arbitrary point in the $n$-ball $B(\mathbf{a})$. If $f^\prime( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0$ for the $n$ independent vectors $\mathbf{y}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{y}_n$, then using (1) we can conclude that 
>   $$ \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{y}_k = 0 $$
>   for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$. Suppose that $\left( \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \right)$ be the unique $n$-tuple of scalars for which 
>   $$ \nabla f(\mathbf{x} ) = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mathbf{y}_k. $$
>   Then using the familiar properties of the dot product we find that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \lVert \nabla f(\mathbf{x} ) \rVert^2 &= \nabla f(\mathbf{x} ) \cdot \nabla f(\mathbf{x} ) \\
> &= \nabla f(\mathbf{x} ) \cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mathbf{y}_k \right) \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \left( \nabla f(\mathbf{x} ) \cdot \mathbf{y}_k \right) \\
> &= 0,
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and therefore 
>   $$ \nabla f(\mathbf{x} )  = \mathbf{O} $$
>   for every point $\mathbf{x}$ in the open ball $B(\mathbf{a})$. Hence 
>   $$ D_1 f( \mathbf{x} ) = \cdots = D_n f( \mathbf{x} ) = 0 \tag{2} $$
>   for every point $\mathbf{x}$ in $B(\mathbf{a})$.
>
> Now let $\mathbf{p} = \left( p_1,  \ldots, p_n  \right)$ and $\mathbf{q} = \left( q_1, \ldots, q_n  \right)$ be any two points in $B(\mathbf{a})$. Let us form the points $\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_{n-1}$ as follows:
>   $$ \mathbf{v}_1 = \left( q_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n \right), \ \mathbf{v}_2 = \left( q_1, q_2, p_3, \ldots, p_n \right), \ \ldots, \ \mathbf{v}_{n-1} = \left( q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_{n-1}, p_n \right).     $$
>
> As the points $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{v}_1$ both lie in $B(\mathbf{a})$, so does the line segment jointing these two points, which is the set 
>   $$\left\{ \ (1-\lambda) \mathbf{p} + \lambda \mathbf{v}_1 \ \colon \ 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1 \ \right\} = \left\{ \  \left( (1-\lambda) p_1 + \lambda q_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n \right) \ \colon \ 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1 \ \right\}. $$ 
>   So by the mean value theorem we can find a real number $\lambda  \in (0, 1)$ such that 
>   $$  f( \mathbf{p} ) - f \left( \mathbf{v}_1 \right) = D_1 f \left( (1-\lambda) \mathbf{p} + \lambda \mathbf{v}_1  \right), $$
>   and hence by virtue of (2) we can conclude that 
>   $$  f( \mathbf{p} ) = f \left( \mathbf{v}_1 \right). \tag{3} $$
>
> Now as the points $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ both lie in $B(\mathbf{a})$, so does the line segment joining these two points, which is the set 
>   $$ \left\{ \ (1-\lambda) \mathbf{v}_1 + \lambda \mathbf{v}_2 \ \colon \ 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1 \ \right\} = \left\{ \  \left( q_1,  (1-\lambda) p_2 + \lambda q_2, p_3, \ldots, p_n \right)  \ \colon \ 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1 \ \right\}. $$
>   So by the mean value theorem we can find a real number $\lambda  \in (0, 1)$ such that 
>   $$  f \left( \mathbf{v}_1 \right) - f \left( \mathbf{v}_2 \right) = D_2 f \left( (1-\lambda) \mathbf{v}_1 + \lambda \mathbf{v}_2  \right), $$
>   and hence by virtue of (2) we can conclude that 
>   $$  f \left( \mathbf{v}_1 \right) = f \left( \mathbf{v}_2 \right). \tag{4} $$
>
> Continuing in this way, we can finally show that 
>   $$ f \left( \mathbf{v}_{n-1} \right) = f \left( \mathbf{q} \right). \tag{5} $$
>
> From the preceding three paragraphs we can conclude that 
>   $$ f( \mathbf{p} ) = f \left( \mathbf{v}_1 \right) = \cdots = f \left( \mathbf{v}_{n-1} \right) = f \left( \mathbf{q} \right), $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ f( \mathbf{p} ) = f \left( \mathbf{q} \right) $$
>   for any two points $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ in $B( \mathbf{a} )$.
>
> This shows that $f$ is constant on $B( \mathbf{a})$.

Is this proof satisfactory enough? If so, then is it also clear and articulate enough in each and every step thereof? If not, then where are the issues in it?

Comment: Is the mean value theorem available to you? The proof would be much simpler with that.

Comment: By that I mean the vector valued version...

Comment: @MaikPickl I'm not sure if the vector-valued version of the mean-value theorem is available to us here. The version I'm aware of is for vector-valued functions defined and differentiable on closed intervals on the real line. That is NOT the case over here. So can you please carefully review my proof and comment on whether or not it is accurate enough?

Comment: Ok, I don't think that the vectors $v_i$ that you constructed lie necesseraly in the ball $B(a)$. Just for example take $B(0)$ the unitball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $p=(0.9,0)$ and $q=(0,0.9)$. Then $v_1=(0.9,0.9)$ which is not in the unitball. But also you dont need these vectors. Just take $p,q$ in $B(a)$ arbitrary and join them with a linesegment as you did. Then you have by the mean value theroem: $f(p)-f(q)=\nabla f((1-\lambda)p-\lambda q )\cdot (p-q)$ where the $\cdot$ denotes the standart dotproduct. But the righthandside is zero and you're done.